# Where are saved pages stored?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, stock-browser

I have used the stock browser to save a page for offline reading.
It is a `.txt` file, the browser only opens it and does not give me an option to download it.

Where is the page stored, i would like to open it with another app.

I have looked under `/sdcard/Android/data` But there is no `com.android.browser` folder or any other folder which looks like the right one.

Comment: Not sure, but usually downloads are stored in `/sdcard/download` or `/sdcard/downloads`. Have you checked there?

Comment: @Izzy Yes i have. I could not download the file, the browser only opens the link. So i had to use the Save-for-offline-reading option

Comment: I see -- that's of course something different. Please take a look at my answer below -- I guess I covered all possibilities now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Where to find it when it was downloaded

If you have been able to "download" the file, the most likely location to find it is either `/sdcard/download` or `/sdcard/downloads`.

#### It wasn't downloaded, but "saved for offline reading"

But as it turns out, the stock browser didn't give you that option, and you had to "save for offline reading" -- which is something different. In this case the file probably is stored on internal storage (below `/data/data/com.android.browser`). Without root you've got not many chances to access it there. So you could either try with a different browser -- or simply copy-paste the text file into some note-taking app / editor (e.g. [Jota Text Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sblo.pandora.jota) or [AmbleLink Notepad Basic Ed.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.objectvista.notepad)).

#### Alternative download options

If you have to do this more often, or formatting gets lost on copy-paste, you're probably much better of with some "downloader tools". I just know about [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), which offers `HTTP_GET` actions. Depending on your ROM, the shell might provide `wget` (stock ROM on my Milestone 2 had this), so all you need in that case is a terminal app (e.g. [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)), and there simply execute

```
# change to the directory where you want to store the downloaded file in
cd /sdcard/download
# get the file
wget http://www.example.com/textfile.txt
```

Adjust that to your needs, of course :)

#### Special downloader apps

Other alternatives would include special "Downloader Apps", like e.g. [Download All Files](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hwkrbbt.downloadall) or [Easy Downloader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.et.easy.download), which you might want to give a try.

Answer (score 1):

While in your web browser, press and hold the Return button on the lower right side of your phone. then at the top of the page select saved pages

Answer (score 0):

Tap ［internet］ icon, tap ［☆］on top right corner, tap ［saved pages］ on top right corner. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Tap the flag with the star at the top right of the browser and click on the saved pages tab.