# how to change the default download folder on android pad

Tags: downloading

From time to time, you need to download files into your android device, but the downloaded files always end up in the default folder. Is there any way I can change that default folder or make the device prompt me every time I need to download files?

Comment: What exactly is an "android pad"?

Comment: @AlEverett Something like an iTablet running Android :) Downloads always end up in `/sdcard/Downloads` with most apps (to be honest, I know of no exception yet). Daniel wants to customize that.

Comment: I think this is a very valid question.  It's pretty obvious he means tablet.

Comment: Related: [How do you change the download location for Chrome Browser?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39267)

Comment: Related: [Change Default Save To Directory For Content Downloaded From Apps](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47274)

Comment: Related: [Where are saved pages stored?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/31829)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the dolphin browser. While downloading file from the internet a popup appears and allows you to change the destination to save the file wherever you want. Hope you are looking for that. (Still figuring out android pad?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  However, here is a very good file manager you could use to move the files after downloading: [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

on Samsung, swipe down, go to settings (gear icon upper right)
search for sites and downloads

WAIT  - scroll down and DISABLE SAMSUNG Internet! TURN IT OFF!

then scroll up to "Sites and downloads"

"Save downloaded files to" NOTE: ONLY when Samsung internet is OFF will the option to save to SD Card will become available.  I then simply pointed to the Download directory on the SD Card

This process worked on my Samsung 5G FE (Fan Edition) phone.